# can we create a single rest API(single endpoint) which can handle different request structures (JSON) in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, rest

I have a requirement where one rest API have to handle different request json(30+ different requests). the client can send any json to this endpoint and this API should be able to process the request. And every request will have unique id.

Ex:
Request 1 :

{
"Id" : "1",
"name":"john",

}

Request 2 :

{
"Id" : "2",
"name":"john",
"lastname":"cena",
"sex":"F",

}

Request 3 :

{
"Id" : "3",
"mobileNumber":"09XXXXXXX0",
"email":"nick@yahoo.com",

}

Request 4 :

{
"Id" : "4",
"pet":"dog",
"color":"black",
"sex":"F",

}

now, how to read requestBody for this API? can we use JSONObject or JsonNode like below?

```
@PostMapping("/save-details")
public String postDetails(@RequestBody JSONObject request) {
    return "";
}

@PostMapping("/save-details")
public String postDetails(@RequestBody JsonNode request) {
    return "";
}
```

Thanks for the help in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to accept the request as a json string and the use Object mapper to convert to desired type.

Answer (score 1):

An example with conversion and dynamically input body

```
package com.example.springmultirequest;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class DetailController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DetailController.class);

    @PostMapping("/save-details")
    public ResponseEntity<String> postDetails(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);
        Integer idRequest = Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.get("Id").toString());
        logger.info("idRequest: {}", idRequest);

        switch (idRequest) {
            case 1:
                logger.info("Name: {}", jsonObject.get("name"));
                break;
            case 2:
                logger.info("Name: {}", jsonObject.get("name"));
                logger.info("Last name: {}", jsonObject.get("lastname"));
                break;
            case 3:
                logger.info("mobileNumber: {}", jsonObject.get("mobileNumber"));
                logger.info("email: {}", jsonObject.get("email"));
                break;
            case 4:
                logger.info("pet: {}", jsonObject.get("pet"));
                logger.info("color: {}", jsonObject.get("color"));
                logger.info("sex: {}", jsonObject.get("sex"));
                break;
            default:
                return ResponseEntity
                        .badRequest()
                        .body("Identification not recognized");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Example Response:

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)
    o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.406  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : idRequest: 1
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.406  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : Name: john
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.622  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : idRequest: 2
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.622  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : Name: john
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.622  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : Last name: cena
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.676  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : idRequest: 3
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.676  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : mobileNumber: 09XXXXXXX0
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.676  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : email: nick@yahoo.com
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.738  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : idRequest: 4
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.738  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : pet: dog
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.738  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : color: black
    2021-02-27 12:52:37.738  INFO 17984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.e.springmultirequest.DetailController  : sex: F
```

Answer (score 1):

Read you json with @RequestBody Map<String, Object> request, parse through your json via Json parser like Gson or Jackson.

Answer (score -1):

### You can use this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/example" )
public void abc(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String > requestData) {

    System.out.println(requestData);

}
```